# Putting a Navigation Controller inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIScrollView that houses three UIViewControllers so that I can swipe between them like the view setup in SnapChat.

In my ViewController on the very right of the UIScrollView I want the user to be able to select things and then navigate to a new page. So essentially I want the right-most UIViewController to be a Navigation Controller with a nav bar and and View Controllers I navigate to from this page should also have a nav bar and a Back button as the UIBarButtonItem in the top left as standard.

I went about it the normal way, just taking the View Controller and selecting "Embed In Navigation Controller" and looking at the storyboard it looks right, but if I run it, there's no nav bar at the top of the view controller.

I have the nav bar visibility set to "Show Navigation Bar" but still nothing.

Any help appreciated

**Edit**

The issue is more than likely to do with how I add the view controller to the UIScrollView which is as follows:

```
let settingsStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingsView", bundle: nil)
let settingsViewController = settingsStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController")
self.addChildViewController(settingsViewController)
self.scrollView!.addSubview(settingsViewController.view)
```

So I'm only adding the view. So how would I add it as a Navigation Controller? Or can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is that you are adding your `view controller` directly inside the scroll view but you should add the `navigation controller` inside the `ScrollView`.
So go to story board create a `StoryboardID` for that navigationController which is attached to `SettingsViewController` and then replace the `SettingViewController` ID with your `navigationController's` Storyboard ID.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use addChildViewController

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^ __nullable)(void))animations completion:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```